# Spring Security always getting 401 on all requests except get

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, postman

I'm very new to Spring security my   WebSecurityConfiguration.kt class looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class WebSecurityConfiguration: WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

@Autowired
lateinit var authenticationEntryPoint: WebSecurityEntryPoint

@Autowired
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun configureGlobal(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password(passwordEncoder().encode("du"))
            .authorities(Role.ADMIN.poziom)
}

@Throws(Exception::class)
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/securityNone").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/marka/insert").authenticated() // but I beted this would help
            .anyRequest().authenticated() // I know this should cover all requests
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .formLogin()



}

@Bean
fun passwordEncoder(): PasswordEncoder {
    return BCryptPasswordEncoder()
}




}
```

And My problem is when I'm making any requests I always get 401 or 403 error(sometimes 401 and sometimes 403 in the same cases) error code but except making
GET requests which return 200 code and seem to work. Also login via login form in browser works.
I'm using postman to make a request I use basic Auth and yes I click preview auth before making a request

[image]

[image]

[image]

What do I do wrong? Please help friends. Without having this solved I'm unable to work on anything else in this project.

[EDIT 30 III 2020]

I sort of have solved the problem partially:

The requests work if made via front-end or curl command
using an option -u user:du so the full command for the JSON like this:

```
{
"id" : -1,
 "nazwa" : "Mercedes",
 "models" : [ ]
}
```

the full curl command would be:

```
curl -u user:du -X PUT -d @mercedes.json http://localhost:8091/marka/insert -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

if mercedes.json is located in the directory from the command was called.

BUT

The sending request via postman still does not work.

Any ideas friends?

Comment: What happens if you set ```permitAll()``` for all routes?

Comment: I tryed this `.antMatchers("/marka/**").permitAll()    .anyRequest().permitAll()` And its still 403

Comment: Could you try disabling `csrf` ,  `http.csrf().disable()`

Comment: It worked! thanks, I think both suggestions dis the trick. I need to read more on the csrf since I don't know what it does.

Comment: But when i did ` .antMatchers("/marka/**").authenticated() .anyRequest().authenticated()` it returnes 401 so it does not do what I wanted exacly.

Comment: I have a guess that you first need to send a request to `/login`, and when you'll get the jsession cookie only then send requests to all the other endpoints.
Let me know if this approach helped somehow.